# Error occured on trying to use double click () for editing a field on saas

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, salesforce

Using the below Code i am trying to double click a text field and edit it with a value.

The error occured when running the script says-

### Heading

### Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException:Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":".//[@id='00N28000001bbuD']"}

Below is the set of code used-

```
WebElement Fieldvalue;
Fieldvalue= driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='00N28000001bbuD_ilecell']"));
//Fieldvalue= driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='00N28000001bbuD']"));
action.moveToElement(Fieldvalue).doubleClick().perform();
driver.findElement(By.id(".//*[@id='00N28000001bbuD']")).sendKeys("60000");
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='bottomButtonRow']/input[1]")).click();
```

You might observe one thing that the xpath used to find the element is different than the webelement where i want to perform the edit.

The reason for this is -

```
Fieldvalue= driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='00N28000001bbuD_ilecell']"));
```

Helps me find the complete row

and

```
driver.findElement(By.id(".//*[@id='00N28000001bbuD']")).sendKeys("60000");
```

is the section in the above selected row where the edit should occur.

I did try keeping both the ids same, but in both the occassions the script failed.

Can anyone assist?

Comment: please provide html code of the element. it looks like id is dynamic.. need to use another locator

Comment: You are providing xpath but you are using locator as Id which is wrong..try By.xpath(".//*[@id='00N28000001bbuD']")

Answer (score 0):

You're using **By.id** with an **xpath** locator, that's why it fails. Change this:

```
driver.findElement(By.id(".//*[@id='00N28000001bbuD']")).sendKeys("60000");
```

To this:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='00N28000001bbuD']")).sendKeys("60000");
```

Or this:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("00N28000001bbuD")).sendKeys("60000");
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the required change. The script worked good after fixing the small mistake and changing the required code.